# Proof in Coq that equality is reflexivity

Tags: equality, coq, type-theory

The HOTT book writes on page 51:
... we can prove by path induction on p: x = y  that

```
 $(x, y, p) =_{ \sum_{(x,y:A)} (x=y)} (x, x, refl x)$ .
```

Can someone show me how to prove this in Coq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it *is* possible to prove this result in Coq:

```
Notation "y ; z" := (existT _ y z) (at level 80, right associativity).

Definition hott51 T x y e :
  (x; y; e) = (x; x; eq_refl) :> {x : T & {y : T & x = y} } :=
  match e with
  | eq_refl => eq_refl
  end.
```

Here, I've used a semicolon tuple notation to express dependent pairs; in Coq, `{x : T & T x}` is the sigma type `\sum_{x : T} T x`. There is also a slightly easier-to-read variant, where we do not mention `y`:

```
Definition hott51' T x e : (x; e) = (x; eq_refl) :> {y : T & x = y} :=
  match e with
  | eq_refl => eq_refl
  end.
```

If you're not used to writing proof terms by hand, this code might look a bit mysterious, but it is doing exactly what the HoTT book says: proceeding by path induction. There's one crucial bit of information that is missing here, which are the *type annotations* needed to do path induction. Coq is able to infer those, but we can ask it to tell us what they are explicitly by printing the term. For `hott51'`, we get the following (after some rewriting):

```
hott51' = 
fun (T : Type) (x : T) (e : x = x) =>
match e as e' in _ = y' return (y'; e') = (x; eq_refl) with
| eq_refl => eq_refl
end
     : forall (T : Type) (x : T) (e : x = x),
       (x; e) = (x; eq_refl)
```

The important detail there is that in the return type of the `match`, both `x` and `e` are generalized to `y'` and `e'`. *The only reason this is possible* is because we wrapped `x` in a pair. Consider what would happen if we tried proving UIP:

```
Fail Definition uip T (x : T) (e : x = x) : e = eq_refl :=
  match e as e' in _ = y' return e' = eq_refl with
  | eq_refl => eq_refl
  end.
```

Here, Coq complains, saying:

```
The command has indeed failed with message:
In environment
T : Type
x : T
e : x = x
y' : T
e' : x = y'
The term "eq_refl" has type "x = x" while it is expected to have type
 "x = y'" (cannot unify "x" and "y'").
```

What this error message is saying is that, in the return type of the  `match`, the `e'` has type `x = y'`, where `y'` is generalized. This means that the equality `e' = eq_refl` is ill-typed, because the right-hand side must have type `x = x` or `y' = y'`.

Comment: The hott51' definition gives the following error on COQ8.4 on MAC: Error: Illegal application (Type Error): 
The term "existT" of type
 "forall (A : Type) (P : A -> Type) (x : A), P x -> sigT P"
cannot be applied to the terms
 "T" : "Type"
 "fun y : T => eq t y" : "T -> Prop"
 "t" : "T"
 "e0" : "eq x t"
The 4th term has type "eq x t" which should be coercible to
 "(fun y : T => eq t y) t".

Comment: HI Arthur, could you please send a link where the ":>" symbol is explained?

Comment: @Cryptostasis This is probably some incompatibility between 8.4 and 8.5. If you type it on JsCoq (https://x80.org/rhino-coq/), you can see it working. As for `x = y :> T`, it is defined to be `@eq T x y` in the standard library (https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Init.Logic.html).

Comment: With the annotations, Coq accepts the definition of `hott51'` in 8.4. The annotations are not necessary in 8.5. It seems that Coq is cleverer in this case in 8.5.

Comment: My mental picture (not sure how accurate it is applying it to HoTT, though): { y:X | x = y } could look like a helix if X = S^1 - and the helix is contractible.  On the other hand, once you take a slice of the helix along a vertical line (x=y for a *fixed* y), the slice is not necessarily contractible anymore - in the example of X = S^1 the slice would be isomorphic to Z.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: you can't. All proofs of `x = y` in Coq are not instances of `eq_refl x`. You will have to assume Uniqueness of Identity Proof to have such a result. This is a very nice axiom, but it's still an axiom in the Calculus of Inductive Constructions.

Comment: But in HOTT it is possible without the UIP axiom. If I've understood this correctly, then HOTT needs the UIP axiom only for the proof with fixed endpoints, i.e. for proving  $(x, p) =_{ \sum_{(x:A)} (x=x)} (x, refl x)$. Is COQ here different from HOTT?

Comment: Yes Coq is different from HOTT. I can't explain the differences since I'm not that familiar with HOTT but they are. If you want more details on the matter, you should ask Coq-Club

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, this result is not a consequence of UIP, and follows without extra axioms.

Comment: I might have understood the initial lemma in a wrong way. So UIP is not provable but your dependent pair version is. Thanks :)