# Are all proofs of (true=true) the same?

Tags: coq

Can I prove the following in `Coq`?

```
Lemma bool_uip (H1 : true = true): H1 = eq_refl true.
```

i.e. that all proofs of `true = true` are the same?

From it follows for example `forall c (H1 H2: c = true), H1 = H2.`

It would be nice to not have to add any axiom (like UIP).  I found the following thread that suggests that it might be the case:

[Proof in COQ that equality is reflexivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39464476/proof-in-coq-that-equality-is-reflexivity/39474531#39474531)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a proof written as an explicit term.

```
Definition bool_uip (H1 : true = true): H1 = eq_refl true :=
  match H1 as H in _ = b
        return match b return (_ = b) -> Prop with
               | true => fun H => H = eq_refl true
               | false => fun _ => False
               end H with
  | eq_refl => eq_refl
  end.
```

The type of `H1 : true = _` is inductive with one index (`_`). Pattern-matching proceeds by first generalizing that type to `true = b` (`in` clause), and instantiating the index `b` in every branch.

The main obstacle to overcome is that this generalization `H1 : true = b` makes the result type `H1 = eq_refl true` no longer well-typed (the two sides have different types). The solution is to pattern-match on `b` to realign the types (in one branch; the other branch is unused and we can in fact put anything instead of `False`).

We can use the same technique to prove uniqueness of identity proofs whenever the type of the "equalees" (here `true` of type `bool`) is decidable.

Comment: This proof is a central pillar in the [Mathematical Components](https://math-comp.github.io/math-comp/) library, for instance.

Comment: In Coq, for any type `A` with decidable equality UIP holds; there proofs in both the standard library and in Mathcopm `eq_axiomK`.